# Webpack Can't Resolve Bootstrap in Angular CLI

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I'm facing web-pack compiling issue for bootstrap module. I am new to Angular development. when I run **ng serve** command I'm facing below issue.

When I remove bootstrap css from angular-cli.json in styles array, it works like a charm.

[image]

```
    ERROR in multi ./src/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
resolve 'C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
  using description file: C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    using description file: C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\package.json (relative path: ./src/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css doesn't exist
[C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css]
[C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.ts]
[C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.js]
[C:\Angular Code\First App\my-first-app\src\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css]
 @ multi ./src/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
```

Comment: It would seem that you are missing a period in front of the path to the css file. It should be something like `../src/node_modules/bootstrap/dist...`

Comment: @R.Richards You are damn correct!!! Thank you very much.